# How to load return array from a PHP file?

Tags: php, arrays, include

I have a PHP file a configuration file coming from a [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) message translation file which contains this:

```
<?php
 return array(
  'key' => 'value'
  'key2' => 'value'
 );
?>
```

I want to load this array from another file and store it in a variable

I tried to do this but it doesn't work

```
function fetchArray($in)
{
   include("$in");
}
```

`$in` is the filename of the PHP file

Any thoughts how to do this?

Comment: side note: if you are assigning the results of the include to a variable in the global scope make sure you use `global` keyword to use the variable inside a function.

Comment: Closing php-tags(`?>`) in files that do not contain any html and don't actually output anything are not recommended. Because any characters following after it will be output into the standard stream(`echo`ed)

Comment: For any WordPress users, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57558027/how-to-access-an-array-variable-from-another-php-file-in-wordpress

Answer (score 189, accepted):

When an included file returns something, you may simply assign it to a variable

```
$myArray = include $in;
```

See http://php.net/manual/function.include.php#example-126

Answer (score 18):

### Returning values from an include file

We use this in our CMS.
You are close, you just need to return the value from that function.

```
function fetchArray($in)
{
  if(is_file($in)) 
       return include $in;
  return false
}
```

[See example 5# here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: When using the return value of `include`, you should be *very* careful about using parentheses around the argument. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-129

Answer (score 3):

As the file returning an array, you can simply assign it into a variable

Here is the example

```
$MyArray = include($in);
print_r($MyArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [key] => value
    [key2] => value
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**In the `data.php` file, define an array variable with some data. For example:**

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'age' => 28,
    'email' => 'john.doe@example.com'
);

<?php
// Include the data.php file
require 'data.php';

<?php
// Include the data.php file
require 'data.php';

// Access the loaded array
echo "Name: " . $data['name'] . "<br>";
echo "Age: " . $data['age'] . "<br>";
echo "Email: " . $data['email'] . "<br>";
```