# How to format a bash array as a JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I have a bash array

```
X=("hello world" "goodnight moon")
```

That I want to turn into a json array

```
["hello world", "goodnight moon"]
```

Is there a good way for me to turn this into a json array of strings without looping over the keys in a subshell?

```
(for x in "${X[@]}"; do; echo $x | sed 's|.*|"&"|'; done) | jq -s '.'
```

This clearly doesn't work

```
echo "${X[@]}" | jq -s -R '.'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since jq 1.6 you can do this:

```sh
jq --compact-output --null-input '$ARGS.positional' --args -- "${X[@]}"
```

giving:

```
["hello world","goodnight moon"]
```

This has the benefit that no escaping is required at all. It handles strings containing newlines, tabs, double quotes, backslashes and other control characters. (Well, it doesn't handle NUL characters but you can't have them in a bash array in the first place.)

Comment: If you add a double dash (--) after args, any string starting with a dash is not recognized as an option by jq:

    `X=("-sdf" "ksdfj")`
    `jq --compact-output --null-input '$ARGS.positional' --args -- "${X[@]}"`

Comment: with the space between dashes and array expansion, `-- "${X[@]}"`, the result contained an empty result, ie. `["", "hello world","goodnight moon"]`.   removing the space between it, `--"${X[@]}"` gave the result expected.

Comment: @UncleCodeMonkey, that sounds like you really do have an extra empty string in your array. The `--` is a single argument that tells jq "don't process anything else after this point as an option, even if it starts with a hyphen". If you remove the space, it mashes the `--` together with the first item in your array. The only way that can work is if the first item in the array is an empty string or if it's the name of a long jq option.

Comment: @Weeble Thanks for the explanation! I think I'll leave my script as-is, but knowing _why_ it's working is preferred! =)

Comment: This is just saved me 30 minutes of Chat-GPT. Thanks!

Answer (score 51):

You can do this:

```
X=("hello world" "goodnight moon")
printf '%s\n' "${X[@]}" | jq -R . | jq -s .
```

#### output

```
[
  "hello world",
  "goodnight moon"
]
```

Comment: +1 and +10 in spirit: the only safe and correct answer. To handle embedded line feeds as well, `for f in "${X[@]}"; do printf '%s' "$f" | jq -R -s .; done | jq -s .`

Comment: This will convert an empty array to `[ "" ]`

Comment: @JanGassen In my experiments that happens only if the `X` is not declared as array.

Answer (score 8):

This ...

```
X=("hello world" "goodnight moon" 'say "boo"' 'foo\bar')

json_array() {
  echo -n '['
  while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    x=${1//\\/\\\\}
    echo -n \"${x//\"/\\\"}\"
    [ $# -gt 1 ] && echo -n ', '
    shift
  done
  echo ']'
}

json_array "${X[@]}"
```

... yields:

```
["hello world", "goodnight moon", "say \"boo\"", "foo\\bar"]
```

If you are planning to do a lot of this (as your reluctance to use a subshell suggests) then something such as this that does not rely on *any* subprocess is likely to your advantage.

Comment: Note that the property of not relying on subprocesses depends on `echo` being implemented as a shell built-in, which for `bash` it is.

Comment: You should use native [[ and ]] instead [ and ] If it is bash.

Comment: You seem to be mixed up, @DennisV.R..  `[` is the standard utility, sometimes also available as a shell built-in (see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).  It is `[[` ... `]]` that is bash-specific.  Accordingly, I choose the former over the latter in this answer for greater portability.  Note also, however, that the question *does* specify `bash` in particular via title, text, and tag.

Comment: I would like to pay attention that [[ in bash is better for performance as a native part, but [ as external utility is better for compatibility, as you say.

Comment: A possible issue here is that if the array contains control characters (e.g. newline, tab, form-feed) it doesn't escape them correctly, and JSON doesn't allow them unescaped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
X=("hello world" "goodnight moon")
sed 's/^/[/; s/,$/]/' <(printf '"%s",' "${X[@]}") | jq -s '.'
[
  [
    "hello world",
    "goodnight moon"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the values do not contain ASCII control characters, which have to be escaped in strings in valid JSON, you can also use `sed`:

```
$ X=("hello world" "goodnight moon")
$ printf %s\\n "${X[@]}"|sed 's/["\]/\\&/g;s/.*/"&"/;1s/^/[/;$s/$/]/;$!s/$/,/'
["hello world",
"goodnight moon"]
```

If the values contain ASCII control characters, you can do something like this:

```
X=($'a\ta' $'a\n\\\"')
for((i=0;i<${#X[@]};i++));do
  [ $i = 0 ]&&printf \[
  printf \"
  e=${X[i]}
  e=${e//\\/\\\\}
  e=${e//\"/\\\"}
  for((j=0;j<${#e};j++));do
    c=${e:j:1}
    if [[ $c = [[:cntrl:]] ]];then
      printf '\\u%04x' "'$c"
    else
      printf %s "$c"
    fi
  done
  printf \"
  if((i<=${#X[@]}-2));then
    printf ,
  else
    printf \]
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

As improve of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26809278/16566807)

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/26809278/16566807

Script produce few formats which could be usefull when include. Script meets BASH spec, checked with shellcheck.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
        X=("hello world" "goodnight moon" 'say "boo"' 'foo\bar')
#
#       set parameter to define purpose: return_format
#               php5    -> for 5.x
#               -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073672/how-to-load-return-array-from-a-php-file/7073686
#               php     -> for 7.x and greater
#               json    -> for $array=@file_get_contents($f); json_decode($array, true);
#               /none/  -> for JS to JSON.Parse(myJSON);
#       function call with array as parameter: return_array "${array[@]}"
        return_array() {
                rf="${return_format}"
                if [[ $rf = "php5" ]]; then
                        q=("<?php return array(" ");")
                elif [[ $rf = "php" ]];then
                        q=("<?php return [" "];")
                elif [[ $rf = "json" ]];then
                        q=("{" "}")
                else
                        q=("[" "]")
                fi
                echo -n "${q[0]}"
                while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
                        x=${1//\\/\\\\}
                        echo -n "\"${x//\"/\\\"}\""
                        [[ $# -gt 1 ]] && echo -n ', '
                        shift
                done
                echo "${q[1]}"
        }

echo "PHP 5.x"
return_format="php5"
return_array "${X[@]}"
echo "PHP 7.x"
return_format="php"
return_array "${X[@]}"
echo "JSON for PHP"
return_format="json"
return_array "${X[@]}"
echo "JSON for JS"
return_format=
return_array "${X[@]}"
```

will produce output:

```
PHP 5.x
<?php return array("hello world", "goodnight moon", "say \"boo\"", "foo\\bar");
PHP 7.x
<?php return ["hello world", "goodnight moon", "say \"boo\"", "foo\\bar"];
JSON for PHP
{"hello world", "goodnight moon", "say \"boo\"", "foo\\bar"}
JSON for JS
["hello world", "goodnight moon", "say \"boo\"", "foo\\bar"]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).