# adding item to json using bash variable with jq

Tags: bash, jq

I am trying to use bash to create a string variable that will be used in jq to add new elements to the json file. But it's escaping my double quote. See below for "wrong output" produced. I am expecting the output shown below "expected output". What is the correct way to add more fields to filename with bash variable?

My input json file (input.json):

```
{
  "##_Comment1": "Inputs",
  "filename": [
    "file1",
    "file2",
    "file3",
    "file4"
  ]
}
```

My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
update_list='"abc","efg"'

cat input.json | jq --arg args "$update_list" '.["filename"] += [$args]'
```

wrong output:

```
{
  "##_Comment1": "Inputs",
  "filename": [
    "file1",
    "file2",
    "file3",
    "file4",
    "\"abc\",\"efg\""
  ]
}
```

correct output:

```
{
  "##_Comment1": "Inputs",
  "filename": [
    "file1",
    "file2",
    "file3",
    "file4",
    "abc",
    "efg"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with jq, just a shot in the dark. The problem seems to be that it reads the update_list as string and not as array so maybe `update_list=("abc","efg")` and pass `update_list` to `jq` without double quotes

Comment: @Theofanis, that's not a 2-item bash array, because `,` does not separate array items in bash -- `update_list=( abc efg )` would be a native bash array. That said, it would be saner to pass the list as a JSON string itself: `update_list='["abc","efg"]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unwind your situation a bit:

```
$ jq --arg args '"abc","efg"' '.["filename"] += [$args]' <<< '{"filename":[]}'
{
  "filename": [
    "\"abc\",\"efg\""
  ]
}
```

Here, we are effectively assigning `args` to a string in the `jq` engine:

```
args = "\"abc\",\"efg\""
```

If you want set `args` to a list/array, then you'll need to take another approach.

---

You could either format a JSON argument and use `--argjson`:

```
$ jq --argjson args '["abc","efg"]' '.["filename"] += $args' <<< '{"filename":[]}'
{
  "filename": [
    "abc",
    "efg"
  ]
}
```

---

Or you could make `update_list` into an array, and loop:

```sh
update_list=()
update_list+=("abc")
update_list+=("efg")

echo '{"filename":[]}' > test

for i in "${update_list[@]}"; do
    jq --arg update_item "${i}" '.["filename"] += [ $update_item ]' < test \
        | sponge test
done
```

```
$ cat test
{
  "filename": [
    "abc",
    "efg"
  ]
}
```

Comment: For the last case, I would consider `--slurpfile` to read the input file as a variable, and `printf '%s\n' "${update_list[@]}"` to serialize the list into a line-oriented string (if we don't need to worry about list elements containing literal newlines) which can be fed on stdin; that way, `jq -Rn` will be able to get that list as `inputs`.

Answer (score 1):

In the original question, `update_list` is a comma-separated listing of quoted strings, and the following solution would work if these strings are also JSON strings:

```
jq --arg args "$update_list" '
  .["filename"] += ($args|split(",")|map(fromjson))'
```

### update_list variants

If `update_list` can be made available as a JSON array, then @Attie's first solution would be the way to go.

However if `update_list` is a bash array, the solution involving one call to jq per array element is unnecessarily (and might be embarrassingly) inefficient; the suggested solution might also create problems because the update is not atomic.  There are far better alternatives.  For example, the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ) mentions a technique which, when applied to the present problem, yields the following solution:

```
jq --argjson args "$(printf '%s\n' "${update_list[@]}" | jq -nR '[inputs]')" '
 .["filename"] += $args'
```

Or for robustness, one could use NUL as the delimiter:

```
jq --argjson args "$(printf '%s\0' "${update_list[@]}" | jq -sR 'split("\u0000")')" '
 .["filename"] += $args'
```

See also [jq convert bash array to json array and insert to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184557/jq-convert-bash-array-to-json-array-and-insert-to-file)

Comment: @Charles - Revised.