# How do I join elements of an array in Bash and prep the Data for JSON

Tags: bash

```
attribute=( a b c )
```

I need the array to be held in a variable and show like so:

```
"a" , "b" , "c"
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184557/convert-bash-array-to-json-array-and-insert-to-file-using-jq

Comment: Please c.f. [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to asking a question well. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and you should really be asking about what you want as an end result rather than this micro-issue, but to answer the question you *asked* -

```
$: for a in "${attribute[@]}"; do str+="\"$a\" , ";done; str="${str% , }"
$: echo "[$str]"
["a" , "b" , "c"]
```

For the record, this is probably a bad idea.
Please consider editing your OP to discuss what you want to accomplish and what you have tried. Someone can almost certainly give you a better, *safer*, smarter solution.