# Select values that match an element in bash array in JQ

Tags: json, bash, jq

I need to run a script where I have an array of ids, and a json that contains elements with these ids and more data. I need to filter/select the values that matches the ones in the array. For some reason, when running directly on bash I got good results with some of the things I've tried, but not when running with a script. Not sure if this may be relevant or I did something wrong when passing from one to the other

For example, if I have a json file like

```
[
 {
   "id": 1,
   "value": 10
 },   
 {
   "id": 2,
   "value": 100
 },
 {
   "id": 3,
   "value": 5
 },
 {
   "id": 4,
   "value": 17
 },
 {
   "id": 5,
   "value": 84
 }
]
```

And the following array:

```
IDS=(1 2 3 4)
```

I need to retrieve the values 10, 100, 5 and 17.

I've tried some ways:

```
VALUES=$(jq --argjson IDS "$IDS" '.[] | select( $IDS =~ .id ) | .value' file.json)
VALUES=$(jq --argjson IDS "$IDS" '.[] | select( ${IDS[*]} =~ .id ) | .value' file.json)
# I have certainty that IDS will always have 4 elements, no more no less
VALUES=$(jq --argjson IDS "$IDS" '.[] | select( .id == ${IDS[0]} | .id == ${IDS[1]} | .id == ${IDS[2]} | .id == ${IDS[3]} ) | .value' file.json)
```

In all cases I'm getting `unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?)

Also, on the last case, when I replaced the ${IDS[n]} for a hardcoded number, it worked fine. Yet, I won't have the same numbers on each run, so I need that parametrized.

Any help would be great!

EDIT

Thanks everyone for the solutions. I kept the one I understood the most for now, but I'm really greatful with all

Comment: Note that `$IDS` in bash just becomes `1`; it evaluates to `${IDS[0]}`. I'd use `--arg` to pass in `${IDS[*]}` and then split them into a JSON list.

Comment: And `${IDS[0]}` isn't valid jq syntax. It's normal/expected you can't use bash syntax in a jq expression.

Comment: Also, all-caps variables are in a reserved namespace in shell used for system-meaningful variable names; you should use lowercase names for your own variables.

Comment: Insofar as this is a question about using shell arrays, answers can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808855/how-to-format-a-bash-array-as-a-json-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`--arg`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) and then convert the Bash array to JSON integers:

```
($IDS | split(" ") | map(tonumber)) as $PIDS
```

---

Combine that with [`select()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) and [`index()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#index(s),rindex(s)):

```bash
jq \
    --arg IDS "${IDS[*]}" \
    '($IDS | split(" ") | map(tonumber)) as $PIDS | 
        .[] | select([.id] | index($PIDS[])).value' \
input
```

Gives:

```
10
100
5
17
```

Comment: You need braces in `${IDS[*]}`

Comment: This is doing an O(n) search of the id list for every input item, right? That's fine as long as we know it'll always be short, but wouldn't scale well if used in a place where the list could grow arbitrarily long.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for something like this:

```
$ IDS=(1 2 3 4)
$ jq '.[] | select(IN(.id; $ARGS.positional[])) .value' file.json --jsonargs "${IDS[@]}"
10
100
5
17
```

Comment: Instead of passing a string then split it, one can pass individual bash array elements as json arguments: `jq '.[] | select([.id] | index($ARGS.positional[])).value' --jsonargs "${IDS[@]}"` which also saves the number conversion.

Comment: @LéaGris I didn't know about --jsonargs, thank you

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to create a map of acceptable IDs and then do lookups within it:

```
ids=( 1 2 3 4 )

jq --arg idstr "${ids[*]}" '
  ([$idstr | split(" ")[] | {"key": ., "value": true}] | from_entries) as $idmap
  | .[] | select($idmap[.id | tostring]).value'
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, pass `ids` individual array elements as arguments to `jq` using  `--args "${ids[@]}"` and read the values back into a bash array with `mapfile`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ids=( 1 2 3 4 )

mapfile -t values < <(

jq '
  (
    [$ARGS.positional[] | {"key": ., "value": true}] |
    from_entries
  ) as $idmap |
  .[] |
  select($idmap[.id | tostring]).value' \
  input.json \
  --args "${ids[@]}" 
)

# Debug show content of values array
declare -p values
```

Sample output:

```bash
declare -a values=([0]="10" [1]="100" [2]="5" [3]="17")
```