# Store a large array in a php file

Tags: php, arrays

I have a large "config" array that I want to store in a different file  (taking this practice from Laravel's config files).

After storing it in `app/config/myconfig.php`

```
<?php
return array(
  'foo' => 'bar',
);
```

How would I call this in my code if I wanted to assign it? E.g. `$myarray = app/config/myconfig.php`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073672/how-to-load-return-array-from-a-php-file - already asked here

Comment: Thanks @David, made my search much easier ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include the file:

```
    $myarray = include 'app/config/myconfig.php';
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it was this trivial.